# Webcam JS. No puedo mandar la imagen por ajax

Tags: ajax, vue.js, funciones, axios

Al usar webcamjs con vuejs obtengo la imagen con la función webcam.snap y la quiero pasar en una función axios que se llama registroFruta, pero al ejecutar todo esto me aparece el siguiente error:

> main.js:721 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.registroFruta is not a function

No me reconoce la función con axios a la que intento mandar la imagen, con esto mando los datos a un ajax para invocar en este al controlador y del controlador al modelo, pero por el error no pasa ni al axios, no entiendo por qué no reconoce a la función registro

```
     pesoFruta (idProd, peso){
        if( (idProd != 0) && (peso != '')){
            Swal.fire({
                html: '<div class="d-flex justify-content-center"><div id="my_camera"></div></div>',
                focusConfirm: true,
                showCloseButton: true,
                allowOutsideClick:false,
                allowEscapeKey: true,
                allowEnterKey: false,
                confirmButtonText:'<i class="zmdi zmdi-camera text-white"></i>&nbsp;Capturar Foto',
                confirmButtonColor: "#0CAF1B",
                cancelButtonText:'Cancelar',
                width: '40%',
                grow: 'column'
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {
                    // actually snap photo (from preview freeze) and display it
                    Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
                        this.registroFruta(idProd, peso, this.embActual, this.fecha_dia, data_uri);
                        console.log(this.registroFruta)
                    });                        
                }
            });
            Webcam.set({
                width: 512,
                height: 384,
                dest_width: 512,
                dest_height: 384,
                image_format: 'png',
                jpeg_quality: 90,
                force_flash: false
            });
            Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
        }else{
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Datos incompletos',
                type: 'error',
                text: 'Ingrese el Productor y el Peso antes de capturar la Foto.'
            });
        }
    }, 



 registroFruta (prod, peso, embarque, fecha, img){
        axios.post(url_embarque, {option:6, id:prod, peso: peso, embarque:embarque, fecha:fecha, img: img}).then(response =>{
            this.listaFutas();
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La instancia `this` debe ser guardada en una variable ya que a ese nivel no puede ser utilizada de esa forma

Lo puedes solucionar de la siguiente forma:

```
  pesoFruta(idProd, peso) {
    var _self = this;
    if ((idProd != 0) && (peso != '')) {
      Swal.fire({
        html: '<div class="d-flex justify-content-center"><div id="my_camera"></div></div>',
        focusConfirm: true,
        showCloseButton: true,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        allowEscapeKey: true,
        allowEnterKey: false,
        confirmButtonText: '<i class="zmdi zmdi-camera text-white"></i> Capturar Foto',
        confirmButtonColor: "#0CAF1B",
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
        width: '40%',
        grow: 'column'
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
          // actually snap photo (from preview freeze) and display it
          Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {
            _self.registroFruta(idProd, peso, _self.embActual, _self.fecha_dia, data_uri);
            console.log(_self.registroFruta)
          });
        }
      });
      Webcam.set({
        width: 512,
        height: 384,
        dest_width: 512,
        dest_height: 384,
        image_format: 'png',
        jpeg_quality: 90,
        force_flash: false
      });
      Webcam.attach('#my_camera');
    } else {
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Datos incompletos',
        type: 'error',
        text: 'Ingrese el Productor y el Peso antes de capturar la Foto.'
      });
    }
  },


  registroFruta(prod, peso, embarque, fecha, img) {
    var _self = this;
    axios.post(url_embarque, {
      option: 6,
      id: prod,
      peso: peso,
      embarque: embarque,
      fecha: fecha,
      img: img
    }).then(response => {
      _self.listaFutas();
    });
  },
```

Como puedes observar, almacene la instancia `this` en una nueva variable llamada `_self` para que así no de error.

Comment: Muchas gracias! ya funciona gracias a tu consejo

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el formato Typescript para tus funciones:

```
     const myFunc = (args) => {
    //my function code here
}
```

O el formato tradicional:

```
function myFunc (args){
    //my function code here
}
```

(Recuerda que la funcion debe estar declarada antes que se utilice)